# Dot Matrix Printer - Paper Position

Tags: linux, printer, lpr

I'm trying print on Linux using `lp` and `lpr` with an Epson LX 300+II. The overall print works well, but sometimes my user leaves the paper in the middle at printer tray.

Every document I send to the printer I use command `<ESC>@` to initialize the printer, but the paper does not move back to the correct position to start printing. So the next document I send to printer starts at the middle of paper; but I need that paper back to top and start printing document.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try specifying a blank page as a job separator at the end of each print job.

Comment: Thank you, but functionality that I was looking for was Auto Tear (ON/OFF). By default is turned off, once you turn on it's did exactly what I wanted. [link](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=FAQ&oid=23730&prodoid=34222881&foid=34740)